# Linkedin get job offers from a company through its API

Tags: linkedin-api

I am remodeling my company's website and I have been asked to obtain data on job offers that are published from my company directly on the website. I'm thinking about using the Linkedn Developer API. According to the information I have found, I have to create an app.
[image]
I have already done this work but several products appear to me to obtain and create information from Linkedn. What I want is to obtain through the API the information on the active offers that exist published for my company. What would be the product and endPoint that would have to be used to obtain this information?
[image]
Does anyone have experience using Linkedin APIs?

I have been trying to obtain data on job offers that are published from my company directly on the website. I'm thinking about using the Linkedn Developer API. According to the information I have found, I have to create an app. But I don't know endpoind and product I have to use.